# All slurm jobs fail silently with exit code 0:53

Tags: slurm, sbatch

All my slurm jobs fail with exit code `0:53` within two seconds of starting.

When I look at job details with `scontrol show jobid <JOBID>` it doesn't say anything suspicious.

When I look at the files that `stdout` and `stderr` write to, there is nothing there.

I couldn't find anything on the listed signal `53`.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the directory containing the files that slurm was supposed to write stdout and stderr to didn't exist.

In my `submit.sh` script, the relevant lines were:

```bash
#SBATCH --output=log/%j.out                 # where to store the output ( %j is the JOBID )
#SBATCH --error=log/%j.err                  # where to store error messages
```

The `log` directory in the current working directory from which I was submitting the job didn't exist. Once I created the directory slurm jobs no longer failed with `0:53`.

My slurm version is `22.05.2`. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54487158/7483211), slurm no longer errors silently when the output directory doesn't exist from version `23.02` upwards. Seems to have been reported in [this issue](https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8895).

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue as the OP and in my case the log directory existed, however, was on a filesystem that was read-only. To cite the entry from the ZIH HPC Compendium

> When redirecting stderr and stderr into a file using --output= and --stderr=, make sure the target path is writeable on the compute nodes, i.e., it may not point to a read-only mounted filesystem like /projects.

https://compendium.hpc.tu-dresden.de/jobs_and_resources/slurm/

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add that while this error has happened to me if the directory does not exist, the same thing happens if you exceed your quota.

Comment: I have experienced this and can confirm it.  I don't think supporting documentation makes sense here.  Anything that prevents writing the log file will trigger this, and having a list of possibilities will help someone.